# Regex to replace surrounded word multiple times

Tags: php, regex, twig

I'm trying to replace all "`&nbsp;`" in twig syntax when it's surrounded by "`{%`" and "`%}`" or "`{{`" and "`}}`".

For example in the following string :

```
<p>{{ myFunction()&nbsp; }}</p>    
<p>&nbsp;</p>    
<p>{{ number|number_format(2, "&nbsp;.&nbsp;", '&nbsp;,&nbsp;')&nbsp;}}</p>    
<p>{% set myVariable = '&nbsp;&nbsp;' %}</p>
```

I want to replace every "`&nbsp;`" by "" except the "`<p>&nbsp;</p>`" one.

I'm doing the following :

```
$content = preg_replace('/({[{%].*)(&nbsp;)(.*[}%]})/', '$1 $3', $content);
```

but it replace only one occurrence of "`&nbsp`" in each brackets surroundings.

How to make it for all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to replace all `&nbsp;` in twig syntax when it's surrounded by `{%` and `%}` or `{{` and `}}`.

If you are seeking for the *easiest* solution, just match all substrings that start with `{{` and end with `}}`, or that start with `{%` and end with `%}` with `'~{{.*?}}|{%.*?%}~s'` regex, and use the pattern with the `preg_replace_callback` where you can further manipulate the match value inside the anonymous function:

```
preg_replace_callback('~{{.*?}}|{%.*?%}~s', function ($m) {
     return str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $m[0]); 
}, $s);
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/F5nmSG)

**Pattern details**:

- `{{.*?}}` - match `{{`, then any 0+ characters as few as possible (due to the lazy `*?` quantifier) up to the closest `}}`
- `|` - or
- `{%.*?%}` - match `{%`, then any 0+ characters as few as possible up to the closest `%}`
- `~s' - enables the DOTALL modifier so that`.` could also match newline symbols.

Comment: How about [`str_replace(['&nbsp;', 'Я'], [' ', '&nbsp;'], preg_replace('~{[{%].*?[%}]}(*SKIP)(*F)|&nbsp;~s', 'Я', $s));`](https://3v4l.org/6HJk4)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `str_replace`, but the `(*SKIP)(*F)` pattern is also a good idea though not that simple as just a matching `~{{.*?}}|{%.*?%}~s` pattern. Note that `{[{%].*?[%}]}` is not safe since it matches `{{xxx%}` and `{%zzz}}` strings.

Comment: Yes and I think both `{{&nbsp;%}` and `{%&nbsp;}}` are valid. By *valid* I mean they should be replaced with a white-space as well. At least, that's how your regex [matches them too](https://regex101.com/r/yL4kB0/1). You know you can't avoid it by this simple regex. And why there shouldn't be a `str_replace` in place?! I think that's obvious.

Answer (score 6):

`\G` is your friend here:

```
(?:(?:\{{2}|\{%)           # the start 
|
\G(?!\A))                  # or the beginning of the prev match
(?:(?!(?:\}{2}|%\})).)*?\K # do not overrun the closing parentheses
&nbsp;                     # match a &nbsp;
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/fT4mO2/2).

---

In `PHP`:

```
<?php

$string = <<<DATA
<p>{{ myFunction()&nbsp; }}</p>    
<p>&nbsp;</p>    
<p>{{ number|number_format(2, "&nbsp;.&nbsp;", '&nbsp;,&nbsp;')&nbsp;}}</p>    
<p>{% set myVariable = '&nbsp;&nbsp;' %}</p>
DATA;

$regex = '~
            (?:(?:\{{2}|\{%)
            |
            \G(?!\A))
            (?:(?!(?:\}{2}|%\})).)*?\K
            &nbsp;
          ~x';
$string = preg_replace($regex, ' ', $string);

?>
```

A full code example can be found on [**ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/r7tKYS).

Comment: @Fiti: Both solutions here are complex. The easy one is [`preg_replace_callback('~{{.*?}}|{%.*?%}~s', function ($m) { return str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $m[0]); }, $s);`](http://ideone.com/F5nmSG).

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

```
&nbsp;(?=(?:(?!{[{%]).)*[%}]})
```

Explanation:

```
&nbsp;              # Match non-breaking spaces (HTML entity)
(?=                 # Start of positive lookahead
    (?:                 # Start of non-capturing group (a)
        (?!{[{%])           # Asserts that next 2 characters are not {{ or {% (negative lookahead)
    .)*                 # Match any other characters (greedy) (except new-lines) (end of (a))
    [%}]}               # Up to a }} or %}
)                   # End of positive lookahead
```

In simple words it means all `&nbsp;`s that are finally followed by `%}` or `}}` and asserts they are within a {{...}} or {%...%} block.

### Note

If you have ending delimiters not in the same line like below:

```
<p>{{ myFunction()&nbsp;

}}</p>    
<p>&nbsp;</p>    
<p>{{ number|number_format(2, "&nbsp;.&nbsp;", '&nbsp;,&nbsp;')&nbsp;

}}</p>    
<p>{% set myVariable = '&nbsp;&nbsp;'
%}</p>
```

Then you will need `s` modifier on by appending `(?s)` to regex:

```
(?s)&nbsp;(?=(?:(?!{[{%]).)*[%}]})
```

*You may use it by default as well.*

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/mY9oG3/2)

PHP:

```
preg_replace('/&nbsp;(?=(?:(?!{[{%]).)*[%}]})/', ' ', $input);
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/H8BcT)